# How to move VLC window by clicking on video?

Tags: 11.04, vlc

In Windows/OS X I could move the VLC windows in which a video was playing by clicking on the title bar *and* by clicking on the video itself. How can I enable this functionality in Ubuntu? I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with VLC 1.1.9.

Comment: https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/5931

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this function is supported in vlc. But you could do the same by hiting ALT and then use the movie to move the vlc window.

Comment: I can do Alt+F7 then use the D-pad to move the window and press return to accept but that is still a lot of work. What I want is the ability to be kind of sloppy with my mouse because I am watching on a TV. So the precision required to click on the window's menu bar is a little annoying at times.